# C system behavior on stdin with redirection

Tags: c, fork, system, stdin, file-descriptor

I am playing a bit with the system function and file rediction and found a strange behavior that I don't really understand.

I have a first process that reads stdin and then fork (calling system function) on another process that also reads stdin.

In the first case I don't redirect anything to the first process' stdin, everything is working as desired, both processes read from my prompt.

But in the second case I pipe or redirect a file to the first process, the forked process start reading "random" data.

Here is an example of my simulation:

fork.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[10];
    fgets(buf,10,stdin);
    printf("Buff: %s\n", buf);
    system("./print");
    fgets(buf,10,stdin);
    printf("Buff: %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

print.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char buf[10];
    fgets(buf,10,stdin);
    printf("Buff: %s\n", buf);
}
```

If I run

```
echo "just another awesome input" | ./fork
```

I get

```
Buff: just anot
Buff: Ðhuÿ
Buff: her aweso
```

And for the child, the input is always different (I guess it is reading some random place in memory...).

Can anyone explain this behavior? I know the child inherit the file descriptors at fork, but I don't understand why it can't just read the same input than the parent, or at least, something deterministic.

I wonder if there is a trick when calling my fork program to say I want "fork" to have this input, and its child another input.

Comment: Q: Could you show us the fork() (and, presumably, subsequent exec())?

Comment: The fork is done by system (`system("./print");` in my code).

Comment: from `man system`, it is forking executing shell like this: `execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);`, so the io streams it is receiving are totally different.

Comment: Having look to system.c and man exec, execl does not change anything to the file descriptors. Having a look to strace, it seems that the parent consumes the full input at once, that would explain why the child cannot read it. But I wonder if there is a way to pass something to the child (without changing the C code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completing Jonathan's answer.

The child indeed receives EOF. The reason is that the parent is reading more than just fgets requests. Strace shows that the parent reads blocks of 4096 bytes.
So if you want to pass some data directly to the child process, you just need to write just after the 4096 first bytes.

E.g.

```
$ python -c 'print "0*4096"+"123"' | ./fork
Buff: 0000000000
Buff: 123

Buff: 0000000000
```

Another funny method is to use cat to read from prompt.

```
$ (echo "once upon a time";cat) | ./fork
Buff: once upon
test               <-- I am prompted here
Buff: test

Buff:  a time
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the error status returned by the `fgets()` in the child process and report EOF when `fgets()` reports it.

The parent process has read a buffer full of information from the pipe, and will dole it out in 9 characters + null byte increments.  Since the information is already gone from the pipe, the child can't read anything and reports EOF.  The parent continues with the material from its buffered input.

**Always** check I/O calls (especially input calls) for success.

#### fork.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[10];
    if (fgets(buf,10,stdin) != 0)
      printf("Buff-1: %s\n", buf);
    else
      printf("Buff-1: EOF detected\n");
    system("./print");
    if (fgets(buf,10,stdin) != 0)
      printf("Buff-2: %s\n", buf);
    else
      printf("Buff-2: EOF detected\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### print.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[10];
    if (fgets(buf,10,stdin) != 0)
      printf("Buff-C: %s\n", buf);
    else
      printf("Buff-C: <<EOF>>\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample runs

In the first run, I typed the input at the keyboard.  After printing 'similitud', the system appeared to hang, so I typed 'miscellaneous', and the child process reported 'miscellan' (and could have reported 'eous' had it continued reading).  The parent process, meanwhile, continued to report on the data from the 'ude' line.

In the second example, as predicted, the child process reported EOF because the parent had read all the data from the pipe in its first input operation.

```
$ ./fork
similitude and gratitude and attitude and longitude, dude!
Buff-1: similitud
miscellaneous
Buff-C: miscellan
Buff-2: e and gra
$ echo "just another awesome input" | ./fork
Buff-1: just anot
Buff-C: <<EOF>>
Buff-2: her aweso
$
```